# WSO2 Identity Server - Remove `Internal/everyone` from JWT access token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Roles+and+Permissions

This documentation mentions the `Internal/everyone` role that is assigned to all WSO2 users.  I return the roles in my JWT token and I don't want `Internal/everyone` role to show up in my token.  Is this possible?

Example below:

```
{
  ...
  "roles": [
    "Internal/everyone",
  ],
  ...
}
```

I don't want this `Internal/everyone` role returned in my JWT.

Comment: Which JWT token are we talking about?
JWT access token?

Comment: Yes, JWT access token

Comment: I dont know how to remove it, but you surely can change the name in JWT with some other more meaningful role name for SP. Let me kow if you need to know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm interested in removing it, not changing the name

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm interested in removing it, not changing the name